# Oracle SQL Regular Expression RegExp_SubStr End Of Line (chr(10) in search text returns null

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

I am trying to get a specific part of a text with Oracle regular expression. If there is no end of line character (`chr(10)`) in the text, I get what I want. But if there is an end of line character, it returns null. You can see the sample sql codes below.

> ```
> SELECT RegExp_SubStr('TEXT_BEGIN Line 1 Line 2 TEXT_END',  
>                      'TEXT_BEGIN(.+)TEXT_END', 1, 1, NULL, 1) 
>   FROM dual;
> ```
>
> *returns* 
>      `Line 1 Line 2`

with end of line char.

> ```
> SELECT RegExp_SubStr('TEXT_BEGIN Line 1' || chr(10) || 'Line 2 TEXT_END', 
>                      'TEXT_BEGIN(.+)TEXT_END', 1, 1, NULL, 1) 
>     FROM dual;
> ```
>
> *returns*
>       `NULL`

It may be a solution to convert the end of line characters in the text to a special character such as `## CHR10 ##` before `SubStr` and then back after `SubStr`. But I want a simple solution without hack.

Comment: Obviously your pattern will not match because they are two diferent lines,one line starting with `TEXT_BEGIN` and the next line begining with `Line 2`, whereas the pattern searches only for strings begining with `TEXT_BEGIN`

Comment: @Fact It is not obvious at all to me, but see Math Guy's answer below.

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen the pattern DID NOTmatch so it returned Null..not sure what you interprete by my comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, the dot does not match the newline character.

The fifth argument to `regexp_substr` (which you have as `NULL` in your example) is used for a few modifiers. One of them is `'n'` to allow the dot to match newline.

So - it's really easy: change the fifth argument from `NULL` to `'n'`.